# I want to allow a specific webpage to open only once in every 24 hours for users

Tags: php, session, cookies, html

A user should be allowed to access a webpage only once in every 24 hours.
what do I need for it. I have no idea besides saving cookies but how am i suppose to start with it...any help please.
Thanx in advance

Comment: Doing that client sided (with cookies) is not a good approach. Every user knows how to manipulate cookies these days. Instead you require some server side session management along with a memory where you keep track when a user has last opened that location.

Comment: Please show us your code so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should record in a suitable location, possibly in a separate table if there's going to be many pages that each user can only view once a day. For the first time a user visits one of the restricted pages, record the page and the timestamp.

For any subsequent attempt to view that page, check the table for a viewing record, if the difference to the current time is less then 24hrs, show an appropriate error message, if it's over 24hrs, allow them to view it.

A possible table structure could have fields for user_id, page and timestamp (be aware that both page and timestamp might be reserved words on some database servers).